# How to do a Unit test (Junit 4) to a method that works in a Class that has a Constructor with an unknown object parameter

Tags: java, junit, mocking, junit4

I need to know how to solve this issue

```
public class SigFX extends SigProduct {

    private FX fx;

    public SigFX(final ReportRo row) {
        super(row);
        fx = (FX) getTrade().getProduct();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getStrtDt() {
        return getTrade().getTradeDate();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getEndDt() {
        return getTrade().getSettleDate();
    }
}
```

I need to start Unit Tests (JUnit 4) for this class methods but I don´t really know how to solve the way I instantiate SigFX in my testClass because it has an Object type ReportRo as parameter.

Comment: You just pass an instance of `ReportRo` as parameter to the `SigFX`'s constructor?

Comment: If you can't get any info on `ReportRo` (undocumented legacy code?) you could mock it, then keep mocking method calls that fail with reasonable values

Comment: SigiFX is a subclass, and its methods returns objects and they are overriden... how could I test it with no errors?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in this way:

```
final ReportRo row = new ReportRo(); //I don't know class ReportRo, so it might be possible that you have to add some parameters to constructor.

final SigFX sigFX = new SigFX(row);

//you can access your methods of sigFX as usual and test it as you want
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Need to consider that SigFX is  a subclass.and all those objetc methods are overriden. I don´t know if it could help you to understand the matter.